# R package 'checkmate': testString is successful for vector but not assertString, why?

Tags: r, string, vector, assert

I am currently reading the documentation for `checkmate` package and I find an issue when dealing with a vector of strings.

```
testString(letters)
#FALSE
assertString(letters)
#Error in assertString(letters) : 
#Assertion on 'letters' failed: Must have length 1.
```

It seems that `assertString` does not support test on vectors. Why is that? Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation in `assertString` states that "a string is defined as a character scalar." The function you are seeking is `assertCharacter`.

`assertString` is just a shortcut for `assettCharacter (x, len =1)`